# Why is a class/struct declaration with different number of template parameters not allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class A {};

template <class T1>
class A {};

A<int, int> a;
A<int> b;
```

This code generates

> error C2976: 'A' : too few template arguments

at the second diclaration of 'A' class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first declaration defines a class `A` with 2 template arguments. Anything after that must either be a specialization of that or some other enabled version.

If you want to allow either 1 or 2 template arguments you can use variadic templates as follows:

```
template <class... Args>
class A;

template <class T1, class T2>
class A<T1, T2> {};

template <class T1>
class A<T1> {};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72142d644c91b44d)

Answer (score 5):

There is no SFINAE going on here. You are redeclaring the class `A`, originally with 2 template parameters, to another one with only 1 template parameters, and hence the error. g++ gives a more explicit error:

> error: redeclared with 1 template parameter  class A {};
>
> note: previous declaration 'template class A' used 2 template parameters

Answer (score 0):

SFINAE is about a **substitution failure**; i.e. the problem must be a consequence of what types you are placing as template parameters. Not every error qualifies... as an extreme example consider

```
template<T>
struct foo {
    !@#*&!%^@
};
```

this is also an error, but not a substitution failure :-)